# APEX - double click on interactive gird

Tags: oracle-apex

Below is my interactive grid. It shows data from v$sql_monitor view based on sql_id from list .

[image]

What I would like to do is to create double-click dynamic action on a record.   This action would open new modal dialog and pass two parameters :  1.  sql_id from list above 2.sql_exec_id from clicked record. Would you give me a few hints how to do it ?  I guess a piece of Javascript code will be necessary :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple options to do this - here is one way, by using javascript custom events. I created a sample with an IG on the EMP/DEPT sample dataset with page 88 as IG and page 90 as modal. The column ENAME is a link to page 90 that sets a column value and a page item in the link.

- Page 88 has an IG and 2 page items:

  - `P88_PAGE_ITEM` (a value entered on the page like the list in your screenshot)
  - `P88_ENAME` (to hold the selected report column value
- Page 90 has 2 page items: `P90_PAGE_ITEM` and `P90_REPORT_COLUMN`
- Create IG on page 90 on table `EMP`
- On column ENAME, add the following under "JavaScript Initialization Code"

```
function(config) {     
    config.defaultGridColumnOptions = {         
        cellTemplate: '<button type="button" class="t-Button t-Button--link my-ename-js" data-ename="&ENAME.">&ENAME.</button>'     
    };     
    return config; 
}
```

This is a button of type "display as link", created with the [universal theme button builder](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/ut/button-builder) that has 2 extra attributes: a class `my-ename-js` and a data attribute "ename" `data-ename="&ENAME."`

- Create a dynamic action to capture the click and set the page item:
  [image]
- Make sure to set the scope to "Dynamic". This is needed because the event listener needs to be added again after a dom change (a search or filter of the IG).
  [image]

  - add a true action of type "Set Value" to set the value of `P88_ENAME` to the value of the selected row
    [image]
  - add a second true action to trigger a custom javascript event:
    [image]
- Create a dynamic action of type "Event: Custom" to capture the custom event triggered in the previous DA.
  [image]

  - add a true action of type "Submit Page". Note that "Show Processing" needs to be unchecked.
    [image]

Almost there. One last thing is to create a branch to the modal page:

Create a branch (process point "After Processing") with server-side condition of "Request = Value" with value OPENMODAL and link attributes below:
[image]

And this should be the result:[image]

Comment: Damn, pretty complex and cool explanation - I appreciate it! Now , I need to analyze, understand and try to repeat it. Probably will have some more questions :(

Comment: Good luck. It definitely works, try reproducing on the sample dataset first as I showed. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: well.  the last point seems to be a key operation . But . to be honest , I have never created any branches - it is not my level ;). Would you please explain how to do it .   Somewhere in "Processing" ?

Comment: Branches are a basic component of apex architecture that you should get familiar with. It is the most common way to navigate to other pages after a page submit. Here is a blog explaining how to create one: https://hackernoon.com/creating-a-branch-process-in-oracle-apex-ch2c3yib . Updated my answer with processing point details for the branch

Comment: I have already looked at this site. It was the first one about branches I opened. The point is  after creating a new branch save it and run it, when I try to open Modal Dialog error appears:   "One or more errors have occurred since the page loaded. Open the Browser's JavaScript console to see the errors."   I am tring to find a reason now :)

Comment: As additional debug you can add true actions of type "alert" to the dynamic actions too. And "console.log" messages

Comment: 100% success -  modal opens, both fields are filling with correct values from the main Window. 1st milestone reached.  Now I need to understand what did I copy from post ;)

Comment: Koen, well, I can write : It is working! Obviously thanks to Your explanation and advices. Once more thank you very much :)   There is one other minor problem I would like to ask ... if only you still have a while (and patience): every time before I open Modal Dialog I need to run a simple pl/sql code. What, in your opinion ,is the best place to do this?

Comment: In my particular example the modal dialog is opened as a branch after submit. Any pl/sql code should run in (1) a page process before that branch (logical processing point = "Processing") and have the same server side condition. Or (2), if that code is related to the modal itself it can also be run as a before header process in the modal dialog page. Pls remember to accept the answer.

Comment: Koen , would you help me once more ?
 Let's modify your simple example:  I added one SelectList P88_FILTER. where the source is: "select distinct ename, ename ename2 from emp" as well as added dynamic action to refresh IG after change of P88_FILTER
 Finally I  added a where clause to IG " where ename='&P88_FILTER.' ".  It lets me filter IG list - cool !   But after these modifications the main functionality to open modal dialog after clicking ename link, stopped working :(  Even P88_ENAME does not change its value. Any hints how to modify current code ?

Comment: Where clause needs to be ```where ename = :P88_FILTER```, not the &ITEM. syntax. If that doesn't work can you put in a new question please ? Followup questions in comments are hard to answer.

Comment: Koen, any chance to loot at my case ? I described it with details below.

Comment: updated my answer (look for the new section "Make sure to set the scope to "Dynamic". ") - this is the cause of the issue. I only realised that I missed a couple of days after I posted it.

Comment: Once again thanks you very much.   In fact it was enough to change parameter "Event scope" : static to dynamic :)

Comment: No prob glad it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Well, I modified a bit your scenario.

1. I added new SelectList P88_FILTER

[image]

[image]

and added dynamic action ON_CHANGE :

[image]

with action

[image]

2. I modified source if IG:

[image]

These changes allowes me to filter IG . In our case filter returns always only one record like below.

[image]

and now my problem begins.  In your scenario clicking the link "ename" updates field P88_ENAME and opens modal dialog with proper values.  After my modification neither P88_ENAME updates nor modal dialog opens :(

Comment: Check updated answer